# Vertically aligning an image that's inside an input

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to know how to vertically align an image that's part of an  tag, so that it is at the very center of the page (the input tag is in my last code block, on line 26 or so). Here is my HTML (Sorry if all this code looks horrid, I'm new to all this):

```
<?php
    require ('login/steamauth.php');  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SteamStakes.com</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keyword" content="">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css"> <!--ignore this-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="welcome">
        <?php
            if(!isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {

                steamlogin(); //login button

            }  else {

                include ('steamauth/userInfo.php'); //To access the $steamprofile array
                //Protected content

                logoutbutton(); //Logout Button
            }     
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
html { 
    height:100%;
}

#bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -100;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div#welcome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

input#steam {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bg').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).css({'background-image': 'url(images/bg.jpg)'}).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
    $('input#steam').animate({opacity: 0}, 0).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500);
});
```

And just in case, here is my steamauth.php (It's from SimItH197's SteamAuthentication repository. I edited it a little so that it would fit my needs. It is located [here](https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication)):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require ('openid.php');

function logoutbutton() {
    echo "<form action=\"login/logout.php\" method=\"post\"><input value=\"Logout\" type=\"submit\" /></form>"; //logout button
}

function steamlogin()
{
    try {
        require("settings.php");
        $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

        $button['small'] = "small";
        $button['large_no'] = "large_noborder";
        $button['large'] = "large_border";
        $button = $button[$steamauth['buttonstyle']];

        if(!$openid->mode) {
            if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
                $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
                header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
            }
            echo "<form action=\"?login\" method=\"post\"> <input type=\"image\" id=\"steam\" src=\"http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button.".png\"></form>";
        }
        elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
            echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
        } else {
            if($openid->validate()) { 
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

                session_start();
                $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1]; 
                if (isset($steamauth['loginpage'])) {
                    header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                }
            } else {
                echo "User is not logged in.\n";
            }

        }
    } catch(ErrorException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who reads through this and gives solutions and/or feedback. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Turns out I had to change the CSS up a bit:

```
input#steam {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -21.5px;
    margin-left: -57px;
}
```

What this did was change the x=0 and y=0 coordinates to match the absolute center of the page. Then, I had to make a margin of -21.5px and -57px (half of the image's height and width, respectively) to make the center of the image match up with the center of the page.

More information about this topic [here](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/).

Answer (score 0):

I did it other way - edited function steamLogin() by adding one parameter

```
function steamlogin($hola = '')
```

and edited all I need in steamAuth file.